# Error "Expected token ','" in the structure states:[...]

Tags: qt, qml

I am writing a small project, it became necessary to change the focus to the object when the condition is met. But when I add status [State: {...}] an error occurs (it occurs here). Please tell me how to fix this problem

This is part of my code

```
Keys.onPressed: {
    if (event.key === Qt.Key_Alt) {
        menu_page.buttonClicked()
        event.accepted = true

        states: [
            State { // <-- ERROR
                name: "change_focus_error"
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: error_page
                    focus: true
                }
            }
        ]
    } else if (event.key === Qt.Key_1) {
        menu_page.buttonManualClicked()
        event.accepted = true
    } else {
        event.accepted = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you have nested key-value elements inside a code block?

Comment: I'm currently not seeing the need for the C++ tag, or very deficient in whatever knowledge is needed to think the snippet isn't a hot mess. I'm fine with the latter.

Answer (score 2):

Your states should be defined for an `Item`, not in your `Keys.onPressed` function. A small example what I mean:

```
 Item {
    states: [
        State {
            name: "change_focus_error"
            PropertyChanges {
                target: error_page
                focus:true
            }
        }
    ]
    
    Keys.onPressed: {
        if (event.key === Qt.Key_Alt) {
            menu_page.buttonClicked();
            event.accepted= true
        } else if (event.key === Qt.Key_1) {
            menu_page.buttonManualClicked();
            event.accepted = true
        } else {
            event.accepted = false
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would phrase it this way: You can add Javascript code to QML, but you can't add QML code to Javascript. Javascript code is iterative (executed sequentially) while QML is declarative.

This code binds a javascript function to a QML property named onPressed:

```
Keys.onPressed: { /* some javascript code */ }
```

But within a javascript function, you cannot add new QML bindings or statically declare any new QML objects:

```
Keys.onPressed: {
    states: State {}   // WRONG: Can't do this here!
    Rectangle {}       // WRONG: Can't do this either!
    var x = 3;         // CORRECT: Any javascript code is fine.
}
```

So your state declarations needs to be moved outside of your function. You can however change the current state within your function. Something like this should work fine:

```
// This declares an array of states, though your example only shows 1
states: [
    State {
        name: "change_focus_error"
        PropertyChanges {
            target: error_page
            focus:true
        }
    }
]

Keys.onPressed: {
    if (event.key === Qt.Key_Alt) {
        state = "change_focus_error"; // This sets the current state
    }
}
```

Or, better yet, you don't even really need to use a state machine if all you are looking to do is move focus. Delete all of the state code and just do something like this:

```
Keys.onPressed: {
    if (event.key === Qt.Key_Alt) {
        error_page.focus = true;  // Directly move the focus
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on this [link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-syntax-signals.html#signal-parameters), signal parameters should be passed as function arguments, like `Keys.onPressed: event => { print(event); }`.

Comment: Yes, that's the newer syntax. This is still allowed though. The docs say this: "Note: Instead of using a function, it is possible, but discouraged, to use a plain code block. In that case all signal parameters get injected into the scope of the block."

Comment: Yes, but using a function is considered best practice.

Comment: well, thank you. Do I even need to set a focus every time? Initially, I used changing the focus, since I need to switch pages (StackView) when pressing buttons (pages in different qml files), but I found that if there is no focus on the page, then the digs do not work. With your method, my focus is not on the page, but here "qml: active Focus Item Q Quick Content Item(0x4261f50, "ApplicationWindow")". This is the main page where stackview is defined, where I immediately put the focus on it

Comment: Probably, then this is a question for a new discussion...